# How to get integer value of a spinner value?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adapter

I'm using a spinner which have some numbers . I need the number which selected by the user for some calculation so I need to convert it to an integer value. 
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(String string);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below code sample.

```
 int myNum = 0;

    try {
        myNum = Integer.parseInt(Spinner_NAME.get(position).toString());
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
       System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
    }
```

**How to retrieve the selected text from spinner ?**

Step 1 - In OnCreate Method, add this line.

```
 Spinner_NAME.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Step 2 - In Activity class, add this method

```
 @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

                if(parent.getId() == R.id.Spinner_NAME)
                {
// SpinnerValue_ArrayName - Name of the Array of Values used to populate spinner.
                        String sText = SpinnerValue_ArrayName.get(position).toString(); 
                    } 
    }
```

Comment: what is **position** at `spinner.get(position)` ? Because when I enter my spinners name and input `.get()` It returns nothing

Comment: Thanks but I think I'm not going to use the spinner for this time because it is really complicated. I've created my adapter and everything but it just can't attach data adapter to spinner. I'm gettin Invocation error. I think I'm missing something. I'will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @bukowski, if you need any help fixing the error with spinner, post the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Spinners work on models. Therefor:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(jSpinner1.getModel().getValue().toString());
```

The try-catch isn't compulsory, but recommended.